# FFmpeg: почему gif увеличивается в размере?

Tags: ffmpeg, gif

Здравствуйте, необходимо изменить [GIF](https://v1.std3.ru/e4/58/1458672600-e4588eeb1daf489772202651fb3c657b.gif)

```
ffmpeg -i 1.gif -vf scale=800:-1 -y 2.gif
```

гиф из исходного 2мб превращается в 8мб

Самое интересное, что раскодирую оба гифа в гимпе сохраняю по одному кадру и один кадр весит под 100кб, всего 75 кадров, соответственно так и получается по размеру ~8мб. Я не могу понять почему исходная гифка весит всего 2 мб и как добиться такой же магии?

Тот же эффект с convert и gifsicle

```
convert 1.gif -resize '800x<' 2.gif 
gifsicle --resize-fit-width 800 -i 1.gif > 2.gif
```

Comment: гифы умеют сохранять только диффы между кадрами. На картинке много неменяющегося - вот и получается.

Comment: попробуй опцию --optimize (-O2) для gifsicle. попробуй перепаковать без изменения размера.

Comment: И да, похоже разные параметры сжатия для LZW или используется палитра для каждого фрейма вместо глобальной.

Comment: Попробовал без изменения размера и с --optimize, теперь стало 6мб, так все таки что сделать чтобы размер не утраивался?

Comment: @iormark я в исходниках покопался, но пока особо не разобрался. Более реалистичным видится моё последнее предположение, особенно в свете патентов и прочее. Хотя патенты на гиф вроде уже и истекли. Кстати, GraphicsMagic этот gif вообще не переваривает.

Comment: Спасибо, да вроде в 2006 последний был, просто что то таких гифок много попадается.